# Redirect to a controller in a different web application ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have 2 web applications in a project. I need to redirect an action of my WebApp1 to a view of WebApp2. How can I manage routing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess something like this would help.

```
public IActionResult Home ()
{
    return Redirect("http://your-app-domain/controller/action");
}
```